# Formatting datetimepicker add-on to jQuery datepicker for use in MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetimepicker

I've Google a lot of answers to this question but none of the proposed solutions seems to work. I have the following code.

```
<input type="text" id="startDate">

<script>
$( "#startDate" ).datetimepicker({
  showOn: "both",
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'DD MM dd yy',
  controlType: 'select',
  oneLine: true,
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  altTimeFormat: "HH:hh"
});
```

This gives me output that looks like this: "Sat Oct 15 2016 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)". But I need it to look like this "2016-11-03 09:00:00" in order to put it in MySQL. 
I'd like the screen output to stay as is, but the value returned to the PHP must look like the second example. To do that I think I need to use one or more of the "alt" format options to datetimepicker. But no amount of trying has produced what I need.
Can someone give me an example of what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried to use `format` option? 
`format: 'Y-m-d H:i'`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: When you add anything like   format: "YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" or any other you get an error back from datetimepicker.  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: A 500 error would not be from datetimepicker, but from the code running on the server. Can you attach a debugger to the server side code to see what the error might be? Or possibly see if there are any logs where the cause of the 500 error might be?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was something else. But adding the format to datetimepicker didn't help. At this point I've converted it using; $fixStart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$startDate")); That corrected the date to the format I needed for MySQL. I may just have to stop there and be happy.